# Unable to get JSON response from Express in production

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express

In Development mode, react and express get connected perfectly and I am able to fetch data from backend. But, when using them in production mode, I am getting a status of 200 but unable to get the json response from express.

I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Backend File is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

//middlewares
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// serve the react app files in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"))
    })
}

//port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, error => {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(`Backend is running on localhost:${port}`);
});

// connection route
app.get("/express", (req, res) => res.json({express: "YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED"}));
```

Backend package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.19.0",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "mainstart": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm start\" \"cd client && yarn start\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/g4rry420/armourLine.git"
  },
  "author": "Gurkiran Singh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

Front end App.js

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"

import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/header/header.component"
import ProductItem from './components/product-item/product-item.component';
import Homepage from './pages/homepage.component';
import ProductForm from "./components/product-form/product-form.component";

function App() {

  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState("No Fetching")

  useEffect(() => {
    callBackedApi()
      .then(res => setBackendData(res.express))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  async function callBackedApi(){
    
    const response = await fetch("/express", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
  
    const body = await response.json();

    if(response.status !== 200){
      throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {backendData}
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} /> 
          <Route path="/product" component={ProductItem} />
          <Route path="/product-form" component={ProductForm} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Frontend package.json

```
{
  "name": "armourline",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a route ordering problem.

In production, you have this code active:

```
// serve the react app files in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"))
    })
}
```

Which puts the `app.get("*", ...)` route BEFORE your `app.get("/express", ...)` route so the * route will grab the request and send it HTML which won't parse as JSON.  The order of your routes matters when they can conflict.

Move your `app.get("/express", ...)` route BEFORE your `app.get("*", ...)` route,  In fact, the * route should probably be last so all individually specified routes get a chance to grab the request before the * route does.  Personally I don't use * routes myself because of some of the issues they can cause.

Comment: what about if I want to add any further routes, shall I also add them two times, one in production and one in development ?

Comment: @GurkiranSingh - I never suggested that you add a route two times.  I suggested you have to add routes in the proper order when you have overlapping route definitions.

Comment: @GurkiranSingh - For us to help you further, we need more info that "still don't work".  You need to look at the actual response you're getting with `console.log()` or the debugger and see what exactly it is and share that with us.

Comment: @GurkiranSingh - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.